# Installed dependencies are not recognized (Yarn v3.5.0)

Tags: prisma, yarn-v3

I installed dependencies using Yarn 3.5.0 and...
[Cannot find module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efd8p.png)
[Could not resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7LpV.png)

when i changed package manager to pnpm or npm all it works

I tried update, remove and install again all dependencies using yarn, but it's not worked

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.